# opencv: understanding cvsetcaptureproperty function and argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am starting to learn openCv but I have some difficulties understanding the last argument (double value) of this function

```
int cvSetCaptureProperty(CvCapture* capture, int property_id, double value)
```

I understand this is a propoerty used in c++ but how does it works in the code below ?

```
void onTrackSlide(int pos)
{
    cvSetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos);
}
```

it is then called in the main program like this:

```
cvCreateTrackbar("position", "example3", &slider, frames, onTrackSlide);
```

I don't understand why the pos is never filled or used in the argument of onTrackSlide function.

here is the full program:

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
//#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int slider=0;
CvCapture* cap = NULL;

void onTrackSlide(int pos)
{

    cvSetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos);
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    cvNamedWindow("example3", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cap = cvCreateFileCapture(argv[1]);
    int frames = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

    if (frames != 0)
    {
        cvCreateTrackbar("position", "example3", &slider, frames, onTrackSlide);

    }

    IplImage* frame;
    while (1)

    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(cap);
        if (!frame)break;
        cvShowImage("example3", frame);
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if (c == 27)  break;

    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&cap);
    cvDestroyWindow("example3");


}
```

Comment: You are simply moving in the video. When you move the slider at value `pos`, you'll move at the `pos`-th frame in the video.

Comment: Yes exactly I am moving, I have tried changing the code for the function  below by moving int pos as the argument to the core of the function but it didn't work, do you have an idea why ? void onTrackSlide()
{
    int pos;
    cvSetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos);
}

Comment: Where will be "pos" initialized with correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[createTrackbar](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#createtrackbar) is a function of OpenCV user interface (`Highgui`) that accepts a callback function `onChange`:

> **C++:** int createTrackbar(const string& trackbarname, const string& winname, int* value, int count, **TrackbarCallback onChange=0**, void* userdata=0)
>
> **C:** int cvCreateTrackbar(const char* trackbar_name, const char* window_name, int* value, int count, **CvTrackbarCallback on_change=NULL** )

where

> **onChange** – Pointer to the function to be called every time the slider changes position. This function should be prototyped as void `Foo(int,void*);` , where the **first parameter is the trackbar position**

You defined you callback `onChange` like:

```
void onTrackSlide(int pos)
{ 
    // pos is the current trackbar position
    ...
}
```

which is called by `Highgui` internal callback system. Every time you move the trackbar, the callback will be called with the new `pos` value.

---

From the comments, you defined a callback function like:

```
void onTrackSlide() 
{ 
    int pos; 
    cvSetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos); 
}
```

and this **won't** work, since the variable `pos` will never be initialized.

---

You can alternatively use [getTrackbarPos](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#gettrackbarpos) to get the current value of the trackbar.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so when I move the cursor of the trackbar, the int pos is automatically filled in the argument of the onTrackSlide function, is that correct, thanks again for your help

Comment: Yes, correct. Please remember to mark as an answer / upvote

Answer (score 0):

This code reads a video file with trackbar that follow the reading process.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio_c.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;


//First we defi ne a global variable for the slider position.
int g_slider_position = 0;


/*

    cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture  (   const String &  filename    )

    Open video file or a capturing device or a IP video stream for video capturing with API Preference.
    Parameters: filename    it can be:
    1- name of video file (eg. video.avi)
    2- or image sequence (eg. img_%02d.jpg, which will read samples like img_00.jpg, img_01.jpg, img_02.jpg, ...)
    3- or URL of video stream (eg. protocol://host:port/script_name?script_params|auth)
    4- or GStreamer pipeline string in gst-launch tool format in case if GStreamer is used as backend Note that each video stream
       or IP camera feed has its own URL scheme. Please refer to the documentation of source stream to know the right URL.
*/
VideoCapture capture("../../videos/Mahrez.mp4"); //put your own video path.

Mat img;

/*
Now we defi ne a callback routine to be used when the user pokes the slider.
function to be called every time the slider changes position.This function should be prototyped as void Foo(int, void*);, 
where the first parameter is the trackbar position and the second parameter is the user data.
*/
void onTrackbarSlide(int position, void* data)
{
    /*
    CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES indicates that we would like to set the read position
    in units of frames. (We can use AVI_RATIO instead of FRAMES if we want to set the position as a fraction of the overall video length).
    Finally, we pass in the new value of the position.
    */
    capture.set(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, position);
}

int main()
{
    namedWindow("Video_Slider", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    
    /*
    cv::VideoCapture::get (int propId)  In this case, we want to find out how many frames are in the video
    so that we can calibrate the slider (in the next step).
    */
    int frames = (int) capture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

    if (frames != 0)
    {
        createTrackbar("Trackbar", "Video_Slider", &g_slider_position, frames, onTrackbarSlide);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        /*
        We then wait for 25 ms.* If the user hits a key, then c will be set to the ASCII value of that key;
        if not, then it will be set to –1. If the user hits the Esc key (ASCII 27), then we will exit the read loop.
        Otherwise, 25 ms will pass and we will just execute the loop again.

        We can control the speed of the video by adjusting the waitKey(25). It waits 25 ms to read the next frame.
        */
        char c = waitKey(25);
        if (c == 27) break;

        bool bSuccess = capture.read(img); // read a new frame from video 
        //Breaking the while loop at the end of the video
        if (bSuccess == false) break;

        /*
         The imshow() function requires that a named window already exist(created by cvNamedWindow()).
         */
        imshow("Video_Slider", img);

        /*
        void cv::setTrackbarPos (const String & trackbarname, const String & winname, int position) 
        This function sets the position of the specified trackbar in the specified window.
        */
        setTrackbarPos("Trackbar", "Video_Slider", g_slider_position);
        // Increment the slider position after reading each frame.
        g_slider_position++;

    }

    capture.release();
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;

}
```